Best way to update thousands of records with callouts in Salesforce
We import orders into a custom object in salesforce (goods_out__c).
I'd like to update all our historic records, and new ones being created, with batch apex to populate information from an external API (effectively shipping details).  I have to call 2 API's per request as we use 2 different accounts with the shipping software and with thousands and thousands of requests initially returned (eventually the SOQL query will reduce in numbers as the data is populated) I keep hitting the "Too many callouts: 101" limits.
Is batch the best approach?
How can I remove the error and schedule the batch without worrying about the callout limit?
I can copy my code below, feel free to be critical :D  I can't see anything sensitive.  FYI we ship from 2 locations UK and EU and need to pull shipping details for the same order from both locations (hence the 2 callouts).  I haven't but I can pull product info into this to reduce these, if there is no product in the UK we wouldn't need to check the UK api and vice versa for EU.  It just seemed simple to do the below :S
public class BatchUpdateGoodsOut implements Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable, Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    // Execute method for scheduling
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        BatchUpdateGoodsOut batchUpdate = new BatchUpdateGoodsOut();
        Database.executeBatch(batchUpdate, 20); // Adjust batch size as needed
    }
    
    // Start method to define the batch job's query
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Fetches records that are not in 'Delivered' or 'Collected' status
        String queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM Goods_out__c WHERE Fulfillment_Method__c = X and X and X) ORDER BY website_order_number__c ASC LIMIT 10';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
    }

    // Execute method where the main processing happens
        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
        for (Goods_out__c goodsOutRecord : (List<Goods_out__c>)scope) {
            List<API_Settings__mdt> settingsList = getAPISettings();

            for (API_Settings__mdt settings : settingsList) {
                if (settings == null) {
                    System.debug('No API Settings found for order: ' + goodsOutRecord.Website_Order_Number__c);
                    continue; // Skip this API if no settings are found
                }

                try {
                    // Prepare and make the HTTP callout
                    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                    req.setEndpoint(settings.url__c + goodsOutRecord.Website_Order_Number__c);
                    req.setMethod('GET');
                    req.setTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds timeout

                    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(settings.username__c + ':' + settings.password__c);
                    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
                    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

                    Http http = new Http();
                    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

                    // Process the response
                    if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                         processResponse(res.getBody(), goodsOutRecord, settings.DeveloperName.contains('UK') ? 'UK' : 'EU');
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.debug('Error in HTTP Callout: ' + e.getMessage());
                    // Handle the error appropriately
                }
            }
        }

        // Bulk update records
        if (!scope.isEmpty()) {
            update scope;
        }
    } 

    private List<API_Settings__mdt> getAPISettings() {
        // Fetch all API settings
        List<API_Settings__mdt> settings = [SELECT url__c, username__c, password__c FROM API_Settings__mdt WHERE DeveloperName IN ('Shipping_UK', 'Shipping_EU')];
        return settings;
    }
    
    private void processResponse(String responseBody, Goods_out__c goodsOutRecord, String region) {
         // Parse the JSON response
    Map<String, Object> responseData = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
    system.debug ('processResponse Now - ' +goodsOutRecord.name);
    system.debug ('processResponse Now' +responseData);
    if (responseData.containsKey('shipments') && !((List<Object>) responseData.get('shipments')).isEmpty()) {
        Map<String, Object> shipment = (Map<String, Object>) ((List<Object>) responseData.get('shipments')).get(0);
        system.debug ('processResponse shipment Now' +responseData);
        // Extract shipment details
        String trackingNumber = (String) shipment.get('trackingNumber');
        String shipmentDateStr = (String) shipment.get('shipDate');
        String carrierCode = (String) shipment.get('carrierCode');
        String serviceCode = (String) shipment.get('serviceCode');
        String total = (String) shipment.get('total');
                // Update Goods_out__c record fields based on API response
                system.debug ('Updating Record Now - ' +goodsOutRecord.name);
                goodsOutRecord.Status__c = 'Dispatched'; // Example status update
                if(shipmentDateStr != null){
                    goodsOutRecord.Courier_Collection_Date__c = Date.valueOf(shipmentDateStr);
                }
                // Update specific region-based fields
                if(region.equals('UK')) {
                    goodsOutRecord.Courier__c = carrierCode;
                    goodsOutRecord.Courier_Service__c = serviceCode;
                    goodsOutRecord.Outgoing_Tracking_Number__c = trackingNumber;
                } else {
                    goodsOutRecord.Courier_EU__c = carrierCode;
                    goodsOutRecord.Courier_Service_EU__c = serviceCode;
                    goodsOutRecord.Outgoing_Tracking_Number_EU__c = trackingNumber;
                }
                goodsOutRecord.Number_of_Boxes__c = decimal.valueOf(total);

        
        } else {
        // Handle cases where the expected data isn't in the response
        System.debug('No shipment data found in response for order: ' + goodsOutRecord.Website_Order_Number__c);
        }
}


I have a lot of feedback regarding this code, so most of this is answered with inline comments.
If you're getting "too many callouts," then your scope isn't working correctly. Having a scope of 20 shouldn't be more than 40 callouts, so make sure your code is deploying correctly.
// Prefer Database.Batchable<specificObjectName> instead of sObject
public class BatchUpdateGoodsOut implements Database.AllowsCallouts, Schedulable, Database.Batchable<Goods_out__c> {
  // "this" is already an instance of a batchable class.
  public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
    Database.executeBatch(this, 20);
  }
  
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    // Prefer using inline queries for compile-time safety
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
      [SELECT Website_Order_Number__c FROM Goods_out__c WHERE Fulfillment_Method__c NOT IN ('Delivered','Collected')]
    );
  }

  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Goods_out__c> scope) {
    // As written, we only need to do this once.
    List<API_Settings__mdt> settingsList = getAPISettings();
    // We can reuse objects for performance
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setTimeout(60000);
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(settings.username__c + ':' + settings.password__c);
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    for (Goods_out__c goodsOutRecord: scope) {
      // There will never be a null record returned in a query
      for (API_Settings__mdt settings: settingsList) {
        req.setEndpoint(settings.url__c + goodsOutRecord.Website_Order_Number__c);
        HTTPResponse res;
        // Keep try-catch as small as possible.
        try { 
          res = http.send(req);
        } catch(Exception e) {
          // You should log errors somewhere.
        }
        // ?. is the safe navigation operator, so if "res" is null, no exception occurs
        if (res?.getStatusCode() == 200) {
          processResponse(res.getBody(), goodsOutRecord, settings.DeveloperName.contains('UK') ? 'UK' : 'EU');
        }
      }
    }
    // scope will always have at least one record
    update scope;
  } 

  List<API_Settings__mdt> getAPISettings() {
    return [SELECT url__c, username__c, password__c FROM API_Settings__mdt WHERE DeveloperName IN ('Shipping_UK', 'Shipping_EU')];
  }

  class Response {
    Shipment[] shipments;
  }
  class Shipment {
    String trackingNumber;
    Date shipDate;
    String carrierCode;
    String serviceCode;
    Decimal total;
  }
  // private is the default access
  void processResponse(String responseBody, Goods_out__c goodsOutRecord, String region) {
    // Prefer using JSON.deserialize. It's much easier to read.
    Response parsedResponse = (Response)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, Response.class);
    // ?? uses the right-hand side if the left is null.
    // It's better to return early than use an else statement. Notice how all the indentation disappears.
    if((parsedResponse.shipments?.size() ?? 0) == 0) {
      // No shipment data
      return;
    }
    Shipment shipmentData = parsedResponse.shipments[0];
    goodsOutRecord.Status__c = 'Dispatched'; // Example status update
    if(shipmentData.shipDate != null){
        goodsOutRecord.Courier_Collection_Date__c = shipmentData.shipDate;
    }
    // Update specific region-based fields
    if(region.equals('UK')) {
        goodsOutRecord.Courier__c = carrierCode;
        goodsOutRecord.Courier_Service__c = serviceCode;
        goodsOutRecord.Outgoing_Tracking_Number__c = trackingNumber;
    } else {
        goodsOutRecord.Courier_EU__c = carrierCode;
        goodsOutRecord.Courier_Service_EU__c = serviceCode;
        goodsOutRecord.Outgoing_Tracking_Number_EU__c = trackingNumber;
    }
    goodsOutRecord.Number_of_Boxes__c = shipmentData.total;
  }
}


Thanks, I appreciate it, I'll delve into the changes. I've tried the code, had to make a few adjustments to get it to work but it stuff encounters a similar issue, the goods news is it does update the odd record but I am struggling to understand a concept I think.  Really appreciate the in-line adjustments, I know your a busy human!  On a personal note, this blog post on the aggregate query pattern in 2017 has saved me numerous times!  Never take it down.

The SOQL query returns 10,000 records (or thereabouts in my sandbox) it hits the API Callout limits on the 51st record as each record has 2 callouts.  Even with the "Database.executeBatch(this, 20);" which I expected to handle 20 records it is querying all of the SOQL results.    I presume my understanding of batch apex isn't very good, I suspect I need to change my SOQL query significantly to either limit the results?  I've considered using a trigger but there's too many historic records really.

@n34_panda How are you trying to run this code? Execute Anonymous? Or did you schedule the job?

I am testing via execute anonymous just now;
"BatchUpdateGoodsOut batchInstance = new BatchUpdateGoodsOut();
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(batchInstance);"
Edit's in a partial copy sandbox.  The latest job has 52 batches but 43 failed with the callout error (3 records were updated which is fine, it could be 3 or all of them...depends on the query above really).

@n34_panda You forgot the size parameter, try Database.executeBatch(batchInstance,50).

Thanks for all the help - I've just got my code tested (kept in as many of the changes you recommended as I could, had to fix a few things but overall it was really useful and I appreciate the comments to help explain things.  Code will be being deployed soon.

@n34_panda You're welcome!
